# How to test Azure Web App that requires custom domain without using public DNS

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure Webapp on a Standard 1 Small App Service Plan, I deployed my application successfully to the webapp, but now I need to test it using a specific domain name that on client side could be configured using hosts file.

The problem is that the Azure webapp will only "recognize" the custom/specific domain (ex: myapp.mydomain.com) if I configure a Custom Domain that uses public DNS and I can't (at this moment) configure the existing domain name to be a CNAME to the Azure webapp because it is production environment, I can and will make the CNAME after the application is tested not before.

My application requires to be called by the specific domain name.

So how can I test my application on Azure webapp using a custom domain but without using public DNS using only my hosts file client side?

note: this problem doesn't even exist in AWS Beanstalk so why is this so complicated with Azure webapp. Its pretty basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preemptively associate your custom domain name with your web app and test it via a client using the host file.  To verify domain ownership, Add a TXT record. The TXT record maps from `awverify.<subdomain>` to `<appname>.azurewebsites.net`. Steps to do this are outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked just like you said.

Comment: I think its important to mention that when you are configuring Custom Domains the on screen help links do not point to this documentation, big mistake by Azure team IMHO, it misleads users.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will let the web apps team know to see if we can link to this documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using App Service, I don't think you can do this.
It configures the underlying app to only listen for domains configured in the Web App.
So if you don't add the domain as a custom domain, requests won't be routed to the app.
The reason is that IP addresses are shared, so Azure relies on the Host header to route your request correctly.

You can add the custom domain without CNAME / A record by using the awverify record mentioned by Ken.

Comment: It is possible, I just validated with my own domain name.  All you need to do is pre-validate you own the domain with a awverify TXT record, add the custom domain to your web app, then update the host file on the test machine.

Comment: The question was how to do that without adding the custom domain.

Comment: not to nitpick but the question was "how to use custom domain without using public DNS".  You don't need to advertise the public DNS to test, you just need to validate you own the domain with an awverify record. Then, you can add your custom domain to the web app and test with a host file.

Comment: Ooh right, I see now what you are saying. So add the awverify record which enables adding the domain and then it'll work :)

Comment: You got it.  I have done this for multiple customers when we transition their sites to Azure so there is zero downtime for the cut-over.